# Formatting flashdrive to back up Ubuntu 20.04: "Not authorized to perform authorization (polkit authority not available and caller is not uid 0)

Tags: 20.04, backup

I got a linux desktop from a friend. It has Ubuntu 20.04 installed but I'm far from familiar with Linux and I want to run Fusion 360 which is a Windows software. I tried installing Lutris and Wine to boot Fusion but after going through the steps, it opens briefly then closes without prompting me to do anything. I tried to fix it... it didn't fly. Now I'm here.

I'm now trying to back up the friend's Ubuntu 20.04 to a flashdrive, with their permission of course. So I can boot Windows 11. Neither of us know why I'm receiving the error that I am. I've tried becoming root and formatting the USB using terminal. It seems to format it, but when I right click in Nautilus to either mount, format, eject or copy files to the flash drive, I receive the error in the title.

I've tried the options from the this link to format the flash drive.
Method 1 returns:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/sdc1: 0 files, 1/1919465 clusters
```

But still the same error as in the title.

Method 2 does the same thing as if I was just right clicking and trying to format from the left sidebar of Nautilus.

Method 3 returns

```
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gpartedbin:9494): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:19:28.898: cannot open display:
```

which I'll google but I find it odd that all three of these are not working. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this? I just want to format my USB so I can backup Ubuntu and boot Windows 11 from another flashdrive... thanks.